# Remove directories/files witch a specific format in all directories from current dir

Tags: linux, unix

Given:
Parent directory test, that has test_1/2/3.t direcotries under it and a file called test_4.t also under it, is there a way to search for all test_ files/directories starting from test directory and remove them ?

```
test/
    test_1.t/
    test_2.t/
    test_3.t/
    test_4.t
```

Tried `find ./ -name "test_*" | rm -rf` dosen't delete anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use xargs :

```
find . -name "test_*" | xargs rm -rf
```

Note that `find` also has an `-exec` flag that let you run commands on each file matching your pattern.

Comment: DId the job, thanks! In the meanwhile, any good place to start with unix scripting and what not, pretty new to everything

Comment: I would say the best place to start with shell scripting is your own computer ;) Try to automate stuff as much as possible, the more issues you encounter, the more solutions you try to find, and the more proficient you will be.